# How do I make an alias appear under taxonomy term

Tags: path-aliases

Right now, I am adding the taxonomy-term part manually to the beginning of the URL as:

inspirational-story/just-because-of-one-vowel

'inspirational-story' is a taxonomy-term. What do I do that I don't have to put this term manually in the URL, and I just write 'just-because-of-one-vowel' in URL alias field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module to define patterns for your URL aliases. Once installed, it will give you a list of tokens to choose from.

e.g. [node:field_YOUR-VOCABULARY]/[node:title]